# Looking for a Conformal Map

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

Given the image, I would like to conformally map the plane minus the cut of this contour to a plane with a cut along the positive real axis say. As pointed out by @saulspatz  Möbius transforms cannot be used.

I would also like my map to be injective.  Any hints or help would be greatly appreciated, this has been driving me crazy!

[image: contour]

Comment: Your cut is made of a half circle+half line. You haven't second differentiability at the meeting point. This rules out not only Möbius transforms but all holomorphic functions (infinitely derivable). Your hope is to do it by "gluing" two conformal transforms...

Comment: $1/z$ maps the given domain (I assume the upper part of the curve is a semicircle) to $\mathbb C$ minus two rays, which can be viewed as a polygon with two vertices at infinity. A Schwarz-Christoffel mapping from the upper half-plane to $\mathbb C$ minus two antiparallel rays is $f_a(z) = z + a/z + (1 - a) \ln z$, $a > 0$. There are two values $a_0$ and $1/a_0$ (given by $\ln a_0 = 2 (a_0 + 1)/(a_0 - 1)$) for which the rays are orthogonal to the line through their endpoints. Then you would have to invert $f_{a_0}(z)$.

Comment: @JeanMarie It follows from the Riemann mapping theorem that the desired conformal mapping exists. The boundaries do not have to be smooth curves.

Comment: @Maxim Please transform your comment into an answer. I will certainly upvote it.

Comment: @Maxim Thank you so much! This is really helpful.  My advisor and I actually just discussed this and decided to take a different route for the problem we are working but it's always good to have alternative solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done with a Möbius transformation.  The inverse transformation is also Möbius and would carry the positive real axis to a half-line or a semicircle, not to the union of both.

Comment: Thanks a lot, any suggestion for a possible map?

Comment: Regrettably, I do not.